# Default error message in browser within angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

If I build minimal angular app

```
$ ng new test --style=css --routing
$ cd test
$ npm start
```

and open firefox on `http://localhost:4200/`, then I get JSON parse error in the browser console by default:

> Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON
> data undefined

My development environment:

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.6
Node: 16.19.0
Package Manager: npm 9.2.0
OS: linux x64
```